# SpringBootのLogbackで出力するログファイル名を、呼び出し元のプログラム名に応じて動的に変更したい

Tags: java, spring-boot

SpringBootのLogbackでログを出力しており、固定の文字列（例：spring）をログファイル名に含めることはできています（例： spring_XXX.log）。

例えば、ログ出力を実行するJavaプログラムが ABC.java の時はログファイル名を ABC_XXX.log、DEF.java の時はログファイル名を DEF_XXX.log のようにしたいです。
ご教示よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラス名は取得できないので別のもの(以下の例ではロガー名)で代替する必要がありますが、[`SiftingAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders_ja.html#SiftingAppender) が利用可能かと思います。

```java
package com.example.jaso77488;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.sift.AbstractDiscriminator;

public class MyDiscriminator extends AbstractDiscriminator<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public String getDiscriminatingValue(final ILoggingEvent e) {

        // ファイル名として利用可能な文字チェックが必要
        final String name = e.getLoggerName().replaceAll("[/\\\\]", "_");
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return "name";
    }

}
```

`logback-spring.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders_ja.html#SiftingAppender -->
<!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation_ja.html -->
<configuration>
    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator class="com.example.jaso77488.MyDiscriminator" />
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${name}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>logs/log-${name}.log</file>
                <append>false</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

[実装サンプル](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso77488)

Comment: 出羽様、ありがとうございます。これから試してみます。取り急ぎ、お礼をお伝えしました。

Comment: 出羽様、ありがとうございます。本日試しましたが、自分のやり方が悪かったためでしょうか、ログファイル名を変えることができませんでした。どうもありがとうございました。